# Scale object with Array Modifier without losing thickness

Tags: modifiers, scale

So I have a wireframe cube that I need to instance (and rotate) 12 times towards the center. I set up an array with an empty as the control. Is there a way I can retain the thickness of the stems? I've tried using solidify modifiers witout luck. Any help much appreciated.

[image: Array]

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should do it without wireframe at first, use only edges to make squares like that with no geometry around it... Then after that try to rotate it and finally then use solidify (or change it to curves Object -> convert Mesh to Curve ) and give it mass

Just like this:
[image]
[image]

Comment: +1 (You nipped in before me... ) If you want to keep this as a mesh all the way, the modifiers to make the edges solid after the _Array_ could be 1: _Screw_ mod. through 0 degrees, with a 'Screw' value to make the extrusion, and then 2: a _Solidify_ mod. Two _Solidifies_ don't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MikoCG, but I should have mentioned I need to keep it animatable through the modifiers. The reason I'm using a mesh is that I'm recreating and animating this model and need to keep the joints perfectly tubular and smooth... Any ideas?

![Cube Model](https://ingikristjan.is/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Test_12.jpg).